# Organization Listing - can I show logos

Tags: contacts, profile

I have a profile configured to list out related organizations from the Contacts database on the front-end web site.  It works great and provides the details I want, however, I would also love to show the org's Logo from their contacts entry - is this possible?  I can't seem to find a matching field in the Profile configuration.

Thanks!
Norm

Comment: Where are the logos stored? Also what CMS & CiviCRM Version are you using?

Comment: Wordpress and CiviCRM 4.7.  The logos are 'uploaded' to CiviCRM Contacts page for the organizations.

Comment: You can do this, and you might also like to put some kind of caching in front of them if performance is a consideration. When [measuring CiviCRM serving images](https://gist.github.com/xurizaemon/eb43fe91f5a505700722), we found it added quite a bit of load time to their delivery. This was a couple of years ago, things may have improved, IDK.

Answer (score 1):

The field your are looking for is called 'image url' it is a contact field.

You should be able to select it in the profile setup. The image will display scaled to 100X100 pixels.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I tried this field but it shows as the full URL to the image and not the image itself?

Comment: The images are showing on the contact summary in the back end OK?

Comment: Yes they do, no problems there.

Comment: Ok, so I added the image URL and I see just an URL in my Listings but when I go into the organizations entry, the image shows!  So half way there - I have set it to not be a 'results' column so it won't show the long url in the listings so that partially works.